# In Spring data elasticsearch is there any clear syntax to query which mapping value is HashMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have one object contains a HashMap[string, string], looks like:

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "customer", type = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private Map<String, String> tags;

}
```

Then I have save some item in elasticsearch like this:

customer1:

```
{
    "name": "n1", 
    "tag": {
        "host": "hostA"
    }
}
```

customer2:

```
{
    "name": "n1", 
    "tag": {
        "host": "hostB"
    }
}
```

I want to query the first one which tagValue is **"hostA"**

My query syntax like this:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate template;

    public void find() {
        SearchQuery query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(new BoolQueryBuilder()
                    .must(matchQuery("tags.host", "hostA")))
            .build();

        List<Customer> customers = template.queryForList(query, Customer.class);
        customers.forEach(customer -> System.out.println(customer + "\n"));
        System.out.println(customers.size());

    }
}
```

The BooleanQueryBuilder looks very stupid:

> new BoolQueryBuilder().must(matchQuery("tags.host", "hostA"))

Is there any clear syntax like this

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Customer, String> {
    List<Customer> findByTags(Map<String, String> tags);
}
```

Comment: can you be specific what result/what exactly you want to achieve??

Comment: exact match the tag, example new BoolQueryBuilder().must(matchQuery("tags.host", "hostA")) query ans is {
    "name": "n1", 
    "tag": {
        "host": "hostA"
    }
}